# For $a,b>0$: If $a^2<b^2$, then $a<b$.

Tags: inequality, proof-explanation

I'm trying to answer the following problem:

- **(a)** For $a,b>0$: If $a^2<b^2$, then $a<b$.

I found a different answer but I'd like to understand The answer/hints in the back:

> [image]

The corollary 1.3 is the following:

> [image]

Doing what they say, I guess that we must do:

- $0<(\frac{a}{b})^2<1$ and hence $(\frac{a}{b})^{2m}<(\frac{a}{b})^{2n} \implies a^{2 (m- n)}<b^{2 (m- n)}$

But I don't see how to proceed from here. Perhaps we should try to show that $\frac{a}{b}<1$ and proceed from there?

Comment: What are items (a), (b), and (c)? Prove the contrapositive. If $a\ge b$, then  by (b) of Corollary 1.3 we have $(a/b)^n\ge 1$.

Comment: @TedShifrin The item (a) is the one I am asking (forgot to write this).

Comment: Much easier to do $b^n-a^n=(b-a)\left(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b ... +b^{n-1}\right)\gt 0$. Whether this adds anything new depends on how corollary 3 is proved.